# AWT-EventQueue-0 Exception

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, java

I get the following Exception when trying to run some apps like Meow

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.medit.gui.entries.EntriesPanel$.<init>(EntriesPanel.scala:69)
    at org.medit.gui.entries.EntriesPanel$.<clinit>(EntriesPanel.scala)
    at org.medit.gui.Main$.createAndShowGUI(Main.scala:73)
    at org.medit.gui.Main$$anon$2.run(Main.scala:59)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/a/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-clion.desktop (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:90)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:75)
    at org.medit.core.properties.PropertyFile.<init>(PropertyFile.scala:19)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntry.<init>(DesktopEntry.scala:16)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$$anonfun$findDesktopEntries$1.apply(DesktopEntries.scala:57)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$$anonfun$findDesktopEntries$1.apply(DesktopEntries.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$.findDesktopEntries(DesktopEntries.scala:52)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$$anonfun$1.apply(DesktopEntries.scala:18)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$$anonfun$1.apply(DesktopEntries.scala:18)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$.<init>(DesktopEntries.scala:18)
    at org.medit.core.entries.DesktopEntries$.<clinit>(DesktopEntries.scala)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Which Xubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.4

Comment: From where have you downloaded and installed Meow? What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: that's the output of java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I got Meow from here http://pnmougel.github.io/meow/

Comment: Are you building from source or downloaded a deb file?

Comment: Downloaded the .deb file

Comment: Do you have CLion installed? Have you deleted the shortcut recently? Try `touch ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-clion.desktop; chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-clion.desktop`.

Comment: done that but the problem remains unsolved :(